# How to add schema markup to FAQ HTML code

Tags: html, schema

I have blow code for FAQ section in my website. And I want to add standard schema markup to this HTML code.

```
<div class="ts-faq-accordion-content">
     <div class="ts-faq-accordion-item">
         <div class="ts-faq-item-header">
             <h4 class="ts-faq-item-question">
                    How to add schema markup to FAQ HTML code?
             </h4>
             <div class="ts-faq-item-icon">
                 <i class="down-icon"></i>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="ts-faq-item-content">
             <p class="ts-faq-item-answer">
                 Your Content Meets Google Guidelines for FAQPage. Google has guidelines you need to follow in order to enable rich results.
             </p>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer:

```
<div class="ts-faq-accordion-content" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/FAQPage">

  <div class="ts-faq-accordion-item" itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
      <div class="ts-faq-item-header">
          <h4 class="ts-faq-item-question" itemprop="name">
            How to add schema markup to FAQ HTML code?
          </h4>
      <div class="ts-faq-item-icon">
        <i class="down-icon"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ts-faq-item-content" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
        <p class="ts-faq-item-answer" itemprop="text">
          Your Content Meets Google Guidelines for FAQPage. Google has guidelines you need to follow in order to enable rich results.
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```